# How to adjust ordering of names using paste command in r studio

Tags: r

I need to have my samples come out in this order: Inf, Inf, Inf, UnInf, UnInf, UnInf, UnInf, UnInf, UnInf, Inf, Inf, Inf.  How can I adjust the code to accomplish this?  I feel like I'm just overthinking this.

```
gcTrts=paste(rep(c("Inf","UnInf"),each=6))
print(gcTrts)
```

Results in:

```
 [1] "Inf"   "Inf"   "Inf"   "Inf"   "Inf"   "Inf"   "UnInf" "UnInf"     "UnInf"
[10] "UnInf" "UnInf" "UnInf"
```

Comment: It worked.  Thank you!

Comment: the person who wrote the answer, why did you remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Recovered from a deleted comment / answer:

```
c(rep("Inf", 3), rep("UnInf", 6), rep("Inf", 3))
```

This has nothing to do with `paste`.

Comment: You can add it if you would like and I will delete my answer if you do.

Comment: Thank you, Z! You've been extremely helpful.